# Programatic support for Coping file from S3 to Emr master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

Is there anyway to copy the file from s3 to EMR master node other than doing scp?

Answer (score 0):

http://s3tools.org/s3cmd will allow you to upload and download files, even sync entire buckets to a linux server through the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [s3distcp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html)

With this you can download s3 files to master node

Comment: It copies to HDFS not to local file system. I need to copy file to local FileSytem on Mater node from s3. I am doing through scp. But looking for any support from EMr library